# Перезаписать значение в массиве при клике

Tags: javascript, vue.js

При клике на option мы записываем значение в массив numbs.Как сделать, чтоб при повторном клике на один и тотже option значение в массиве перезаписывались, а не добавлялись. [Вот код](http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/311834/)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    numbs: []
  },
  methods: {
   toggleClass: function(e) {
      $(e.currentTarget).next().toggleClass('open');
    },
    numberOption: function(e){
      var text = $(e.target).text();
      this.numbs.push(text);
      $(e.currentTarget).closest('.select-item').find('.number_val').html(text);
      $('.number').removeClass('open');
    }
  }
})

$('.number .option').click(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(this).closest('.select-item').find('.input_val').val(text);

  var sum = 0;
  $('.number_input .input_val').each( function () {
    if ($(this).val() != 0) {
      sum++;
    }
  });
  $('.quantity_val').text(sum);
});
```

```css
.select {
  display: flex;
}
.select-item {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.number_input {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.number {
  background-color: #bcbcbc;
  display: none;
}
.number.open {
  display: block;
}
.option {
  padding: 4px;
}
.option:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #d1afaf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="item_box">
    <div class="item_value">
      <label class="select-title">
         Общее кол-во выбранных select:
      </label>
      <span class="quantity_val">0</span>
      <input class="input_quantity" type="hidden"  v-model="numbs">
    </div>
    <div class="select">
      <div class="select-item" v-for="n in 3">
        <label class="select-title">
          {{ n }} select
        </label>
        <div class="number_input" @click="toggleClass">
          <span class="number_val">&mdash;</span>
          <input class="input_val" type="hidden"  value="">
        </div>
        <ul class="number" @click="numberOption">
          <li class="option" v-for="i in 9">{{ i }}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Для начала перенести всю логику в методы vue и использовать `@click`. Vue можно использовать вместе с jQuery, но вы пытаетесь сделать это параллельно.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Я добавил в `.number_val` атрибут `num` в который помещается номер колонки. После, при клике я получаю значение атрибута `num` парсю это значение в число, далее отнимаю 1 (т.к. массив начинается с 0) и ячейке под этим номером присваиваю переменную `text`. + Работает релативно т.е. хоть на неограниченное кол-во ячеек.

*BUG*: Нашел один баг если кликнуть левее черного кружка еще в закрашенной зоне то значение становится "123456789"

P.S. переменную `app` можно убрать я использовал ее что бы проверять значение

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    numbs: []
  },
  methods: {
   toggleClass: function(e) {
      $(e.currentTarget).next().toggleClass('open');
    },
    numberOption: function(e){
      var text = $(e.target).text();
      var num = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.select-item').find('.number_val').attr("num")
      this.numbs[parseInt(num) - 1] = text;
      $(e.currentTarget).closest('.select-item').find('.number_val').html(text);
      console.log(this.numbs) // Проверяю значение массива 
      $('.number').removeClass('open');
    }
  }
})

$('.number .option').click(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(this).closest('.select-item').find('.input_val').val(text);

  var sum = 0;
  $('.number_input .input_val').each( function () {
    if ($(this).val() != 0) {
      sum++;
    }
  });
  $('.quantity_val').text(sum);
});
```

```css
.select {
    display: flex;
  }
  .select-item {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
  .number_input {
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .number {
    background-color: #bcbcbc;
    display: none;
  }
  .number.open {
    display: block;
  }
  .option {
    padding: 4px;
  }
  .option:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #d1afaf;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div class="item_box">
        <div class="item_value">
            <label class="select-title">
                Общее кол-во выбранных select:
            </label>
            <span class="quantity_val">0</span>
            <input class="input_quantity" type="hidden"  v-model="numbs">
        </div>
        <div class="select">
            <div class="select-item" v-for="n in 8">
                <label class="select-title">
                    {{ n }} select
                </label>
                <div class="number_input" @click="toggleClass">
                    <span class="number_val" :num="n">&mdash;</span>
                    <input class="input_val" type="hidden"  value="">
                </div>
                <ul class="number" @click="numberOption">
                    <li class="option" v-for="i in 9">{{ i }}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: эмм... а за что минус

Comment: Это если ничего не выбрали.